# Computer vision in ROS

Tags: ros, opencv, libopencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new in computer vision but I need to implement a robot with these kind of abilities.

1. It has to identify objects with a particular color and size.
2. For this purpose I have a RGB camera which gives me a topic of the type: **sensor_msgs/Image**

I imagine that ROS has its own version of OpenCV for these cases.
What I have to do is a pretty simple task but I have no idea of image processing.

Any idea?
Where can I find libraries and documentation explaining them?

(I am working with ROS Hydro)

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188138/computer-vision-in-ros/) by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 223 on 2014-07-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out [CV Bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge). This converts ROS images to OpenCV images. From then on it's straight-forward open cv code.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2014-07-29**:
Is there any library to process images that belongs to ros?
(without needing to convert it with CV Bridge)

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-29**:
Something as powerful as Open CV: No. I would consider Open CV the image library for ROS.

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2014-07-29**:
thank you very much ;)